# How to fix my bubble sort code for my float array from a text file containing decimal values

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point, streamreader, bubble-sort

I'm using the bubble sort algorithm to sort a list of float values obtained from a text file. This bubble sort code works for other arrays but not for this one; it only displays the first value in the text file.

I have used this bubble sort on existing arrays and it works but it does not work for my float array which i have converted from a string. Why does this not work?`

```
while(line != null)
{
    int temp = 0;

    for (int write = 0; write < x.Length; write++)
    {
        for (int sort = 0; sort < x.Length - 1; sort++)
        {
            if (x[sort] > x[sort + 1])
            {
                temp = (int)x[sort + 1];
                x[sort + 1] = x[sort];
                x[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 1)
    {
        Console.Write(x[i] + " ");
    }

    line = br.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Here is the code for converting the string to the x value:

```
 string line = br.ReadLine();
 float [] x = Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(','), float.Parse);
```

Here is the code executing the file conversion:

```
            using (StreamReader br = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
```

Comment: Please, show the code lines where you convert `line` to `x` array

Comment: I have edited the question now to shows that code

Comment: please show your file content and full code with conversion

Answer (score 1):

Other than the fact that you can get the array in order with one line (Array.Sort(x), which uses the more efficient Quicksort), what you have there (1) isn't a bubble sort and (2) will only work correctly for integers. Your temporary swap variable is an integer, so values will always be converted to integer when swapping. You need something like:

```
   public class BubbleSort<T> where T : IComparable<T>
   {
      public static T[] Sort(T[] array)
      {
         for (var i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
         {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
               if (((IComparable<T>)array[j]).CompareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0)
               {
                  var swapVar = array[j + 1];
                  array[j + 1] = array[j];
                  array[j] = swapVar;
               }
            }
         }
         return array;
      }
   }
```

Use it like this:

```
BubbleSort<float>.Sort(x);
```

after you've loaded your array (X) into memory. Note that it can sort an array of anything that can be compared against its self (float in this case).

Modifying things slightly:

```
   public static class BubbleSort
   {
      public static T[] Sort<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable<T>
      {
         for (var i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
         {
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
               if (((IComparable<T>)array[j]).CompareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0)
               {
                  var swapVar = array[j + 1];
                  array[j + 1] = array[j];
                  array[j] = swapVar;
               }
            }
         }
         return array;
      }
   }
```

Will infer the type of the array automatically so

```
BubbleSort.Sort(x);
```

will work

Comment: I am aware of the sort built in method but i wanted to implement my own bubble sort algorithm. I have attempted to implement your code above but it failed to achieve what I wanted. I want the algorithm to take in the variable that i used to create the array for use in the sorting algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, i have implemented this but i wasn't sure where the sorted array is displayed on the console

Comment: You do that yourself, after you've called BubbleSort.Sort(x)

Comment: After doing this, the console still only displays the first value of the array

Comment: Try  
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i += 1)
    {
        Console.Write(x[i] + " ");
    }
before and after the call to Sort. If they are the same then the problem is in reading the data.

Comment: I have done this, i believe the problem is in reading the data from the text file to the float array. After doing this, the output is still the first value in the array.

Comment: The text file contains minus decimal numbers so there is a problem with the values from the file being read